# Passing right argument to function with `char const* str`

Tags: c, atmega

**Setup**

```
#define functionA(str) functionB(PSTR(str))

void functionB(char const* str) { ... something, e.g. print str... }

void functionC(char const* str) {
    functionA("Hello World");       // this one work
    functionA(str);                 // however this doesn't work
}
```

**Problem**

I have a function `function B` which I try to use. If I simply call it with `"some string"` it works perfectly. However if I try to call it in `functionC` with the argument `str`, the compiler returns the error "invalid initializer" and the message "in expansion of macro PSTR". How can I fix this, where is my problem?

**EDIT - additional information**

The program runs on an AT Mega and the PSTR is also from AT-Mega

```
#define PSTR(s) ((const PROGMEM char *)(s))
#else  /* !DOXYGEN */
/* The real thing. */
# define PSTR(s) (__extension__({static const char __c[] PROGMEM = (s); &__c[0];}))
#endif /* DOXYGEN */

#define PROGMEM __ATTR_PROGMEM__

#ifndef __ATTR_PROGMEM__
#define __ATTR_PROGMEM__ __attribute__((__progmem__))
#endif
```

Comment: What is the macro PSTR?

Comment: don't describe the error message, paste it

Comment: I'm not quiet sure, it was given. It is part of the microcontroller ATMega. Online I found `#define PSTR(s) \ ((const PROGMEM char *)(s)) ` but there you have the next macro...

Comment: With a link to the [doc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html#ga05ca900ebf7cd121be73c654d9ccb3eb), it's easier to understand

Comment: isn't it supposed to be `const char* str` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the error message is just "invalid initializer" and "in expansion of macro 'PSTR'", I don't know how that helps

Comment: @PhoenixBlue tried it, still doesn't help

Comment: OK. First change it to `const char* str` then show us the implementation of `PSTR`

Comment: Maybe take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const/1143272#1143272

Comment: Try if it compiles with `#define  PSTR(s) ((const char *)(s))`

Comment: @Jabberwocky PSTR is not defined by me, it's given by the microcontroller

Comment: ... and are you sure your usage of the `PSTR` macro is appropriate here?

Comment: Yes, this part was given. I had the idea to use another function (functionC) to call functionA, however I'm not sure if this works. It works with "string" but not if I try to use the string passed over as an argument to functionC

Comment: @Vabeyeb yes we know it's not defined by you, but it's still usefull to know what is it...

Comment: _"this part was given"_: given by whom? Maybe syou should ask _that_person.

Comment: Progmem (`PSTR`) strings occupy a different address space – even if you manage to pass the pointer to a function expecting a regular (RAM) string, it would not be able to use it correctly (since it's not in RAM). You need to copy the `PSTR` to RAM first in order to pass it to such a function.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot mix program space and regular strings, since they are stored in different memory spaces. The AVR architecture separates data and program memory, and regular variables/strings live in the data memory (RAM). But since RAM is often very limited on these devices, constant data (such as strings) may be stored in program space to avoid using RAM. The `PSTR` macro is provided to do this for string literals.

The reason for your error with `functionA(str)` is simply that it ends up using the macro as `PSTR(str)`, and `PSTR` only works with string literals since you cannot place data in program space at runtime. But also note that while `PSTR("Hello world")` works, your `functionB` must specifically expect a program space string or it will treat the pointer as though it pointed to RAM (which it doesn't).

To use a program space string, you may either take a `PSTR` as an argument and handle it with the `pgm_*` functions/macros (such as `pgm_read_byte`), or first copy the `PSTR` to RAM (such as with `strcpy_P`) and then pass that to a function expecting a regular string. See `avr/pgmspace.h`.